# Expand All Button Acordion In MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

everyone,
I am trying to build a button that will open all the tags in the accordion without compromising the built-in functionality that MUI gives, i.e. opening and closing the tags separately regardless of the "Show all" button. When I add attribute to Acordion as expanded it overrides the MUI functionality which I do not want. Thank you very much for answering

```
        <Accordion>
              <AccordionSummary
                expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                aria-controls={`panel-content ${index}`}
                id={`panel-content ${index} header`}
              >
                <Typography>
                  {header} {<b>({amount[index + 1]})</b>}
                </Typography>
              </AccordionSummary>
              <AccordionDetails>
                <Grid container direction="row">
                  {stations?.map((station, index) => {
                    if (station.type === header) {
                      return (
                        <OneStation
                          key={index}
                          location={station.location}
                          devices={station.devices}
                        />
                      );
                    }
                  })}
                </Grid>
              </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i understood you but maybe this will help you:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {Accordion, AccordionSummary, AccordionDetails, Typography} from '@mui/material';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';

export default function SimpleAccordion() {
  const [expandAll, setExpandAll] = useState(false);

  const onClick = () => {
    setExpandAll(prevState => !prevState);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Accordion expanded={expandAll}>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel1a-content"
          id="panel1a-header"
        >
          <Typography>Accordion 1</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion expanded={expandAll}>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel2a-content"
          id="panel2a-header"
        >
          <Typography>Accordion 2</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>

      <button onClick={onClick}>Expand All</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```